# Generating a table with fixed width columns dynamically using Angular

Tags: css, angular, html-table

I am trying to create a data table with fixed column width (20% each). I am using div in my table so that I can repeat the row dynamically using angular. The introduction of div is messing up my table design. I need all the rows to take 100% even of there's no value in one of the columns. What else do I need to do to get the desired result?

```
<table class="sturdy">
  <thead>
    <div class="test">
      <tr>
          <th>ID<th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Middle Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <div class="test" *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ attribute[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ attribute[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ attribute[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ attribute[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ attribute[4] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my css:

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%; /* must have this set */
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sturdy th:nth-child(1),
.sturdy th:nth-child(2),
.sturdy th:nth-child(3),
.sturdy th:nth-child(4),
.sturdy th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table is getting messed up because you have an invalid syntax on one of the table headers (closing tag). I also added `overflow: auto;` to the `td` elements when they potentially contain elements that cannot fit in the cell

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}

table {
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%; /* must have this set */
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sturdy th:nth-child(1),
.sturdy th:nth-child(2),
.sturdy th:nth-child(3),
.sturdy th:nth-child(4),
.sturdy th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="sturdy">
  <thead>
    <div class="test">
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Middle Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <div class="test" *ngFor="let attribute of attributes">
      <tr>
        <td>fooooooooooooo</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```